# No files match include/exclude patterns when deploying API Gateway with mock integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I want to deploy a APIGateway with mock integration for testing via serverless using [this](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#mock-integration) example.

However when I try to deploy it I get the following error:

```
No file matches include / exclude patterns
```

Which I don't understand because I don't want to include or exclude anything. I just wanna create the Gateway with mock integration which should give me an endpoint which returns a specific response. I don't want to deploy any lambda. Here is the full serverless:

```
service: sls-apig
provider:
  name: aws
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          cors: true
          method: get
          integration: mock
          request:
            template:
              application/json: '{"statusCode": 200}'
          response:
            template: $input.path('$')
            statusCodes:
              201:
                pattern: ''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error normally occurs when you are testing the Serverless Framework in a directory with only the serverless.yml file. This looks like a bug with the Serverless Framework.

Your project structure must be like the following:

```
project
├── .serverless/
├── serverless.yml
```

To stop this error we only need to add a file on this directory, in the following example I am adding the `foo.txt` file:

```
project
├── .serverless/
├── foo.txt
├── serverless.yml
```

And the error `No file matches include / exclude patterns` will stop to happen.

Also, we can use this file as the template of the response using the following code:

```
response:
  template: ${file(foo.txt)}
  statusCodes:
    201:
      pattern: ''
```